How do you transition from a departure procedure to enroute when the DP does not end on any of the nearby enroute airways?
What needs to be done, if anything, while flying under IFR rules to go from the end of an (obstacle) departure procedure to enroute, when the departure procedure does not end on any Navaid used to define an enroute airway?
For example, looking at La Grande, Oregon (KLGD), there is the La Grande One ODP (LGD1.LGD). It ends on an NDB, which as far as I can tell is not "connected" to any of the nearby IFR airways or fixes:


Say you want to go from La Grande, Oregon to Lewiston, Idaho, and plan to do so by following V182 to the NE to the MQG VOR. If you take off from La Grande and do the ODP, once you are at 7000 MSL and turn to being on course 192 to the LGD NDB, what do you do next to get yourself onto the V182 airway? Do you just fly until the NDB reverses (you've just crossed the NDB) and then turn to a course of 309 magnetic to get to IBEAM? If so, and you're only at 9000 MSL when you get there, do you have to do any hold to allow you to climb to cross IBEAM at or above 12000 MSL?
My interest is the terrain and obstacle clearance provided by the design of the procedures without the help of ATC. (Such as might be used to ensure terrain clearance when a VFR flight is conducted on a dark and moonless night.) I realize that if you are in contact with ATC, they may be able to use MVA to vector you and provide the connection.

The answer is following "thence...". The procedure is to keep you over the valley to 7000 ft. From the NDB, the climb to get above an airway's MDA will account for obstacle clearance by the most logical or direct routing based on the normal minimum gradient (200 ft/nm).
So crossing the NDB at 7000, in the absence of an ATC instruction (comms failure) I would simply make a climbing right turn to pick up V182 and continue the climb to the cleared altitude or MDA.
Remember that IFR procedures are in large part to accommodate communications failures, where you squawk 7600 and proceed as per the comms failure hierarchy  (clearance, FPR etc).
Where there is a gap in a routing like that, normally ATC will fill it for you with an instruction, but with a comm failure you are expected to proceed in a logical and predictable way so ATC can anticipate your moves. If you squawked 7600 while on that departure approaching the NDB, ATC will expect you to cross it and proceed to the airway in your original clearance by the most logical route, which would be a right turn to intercept the track and proceed on course while climbing.

So is it fair to say, then, that the ODP was designed (by selecting the 7000 MSL number) for obstacle/terrain clearance such that if you are climbing at the normal minimum gradient, it does not matter which direction you go? To put it another way, there is a "cone" of obstacle-free space starting at the NDB at 7000 MSL slanting up at 200 ft/nm? For example, once you reach the NDB, could you turn direct to the ALW VOR as long as you kept climbing at 200ft/nm until you got to at least 12200 MSL (probably 13000 as an IFR cruising altitude)?

Yes.  It's the same for an airport. You can draw an imaginary inverted cone with a slope of 200 ft/nm from the departure end of each runway and expect obstacle clearance from the runway to whatever the lowest IFR altitude is in any direction as long as you stay above the cone's plane.  If there were any special requirements, there would be an instruction in the departure chart with a hold depicted and an instruction to maintain the hold while climbing until above altitude X.  Check the MSA sector alts on the approach charts and you will see there is plenty of margin.
